# push notification when the timer span is zero in xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

i write app in xamarin.android that have timer span to next update and when the timer became zero app start to download new update from the server.

```
    public static DateTime NextUpdateTime = new DateTime(2017, 3, 12, 0, 0, 0);
    TimeSpan ts = CLS.Code.Statics.NextUpdateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
```

but when it is zero until program not opened update will not download update.

i need service in xamarin.android that show notification that new update is released and when click on notification app will open.

Comment: Will your app have backend connection? if so why don't you move this logic to a server and from the server you send the push notification whenever the user needs to download the update?

Comment: how i use push notification server

Comment: and i like to do this with services